# RAM info with dmidecode --type 17

Tags: ram, dmidecode

On the motherboard ASUS V-PRO Z77 installed 2x2 (Kingston and Corsair) memory slots. All four slats of RAM do not cause any complaints. They work properly. But, below is the output of the result of running the dmidecode program and in the output I'm interested in the following lines:
Error Information Handle: 0x0060
Error Information Handle: 0x0063
What does it mean?
What are the reasons for these errors?
Unfortunately, I could not find information about this in Google.

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type 17
# dmidecode 2.12
# SMBIOS entry point at 0x000f04c0
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x005B, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x005C
    Error Information Handle: 0x0060
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 9333B00B
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: 99U5584-007.A00LF 
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x005F, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x005C
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: 029E
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x0062, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x005C
    Error Information Handle: 0x0063
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 1D10C373
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: 99U5584-018.A00LF 
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x0065, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x005C
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 3
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: 029E
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz
```

**UPD**

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type 18
# dmidecode 2.12
# SMBIOS entry point at 0x000f04c0
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x005D, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x0060, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x0063, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x0066, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
```

Comment: FYI: this is a clone of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49719304/ram-info-with-dmidecode-type-17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think your parsing the info from dmidecode in the way it was intended. What I see here is that your Kingston modules are [error correcting](https://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR1333D3E9S_4GHC.pdf) while your Corsair modules [are not.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FZ5V18K)

To the best of my knowledge, The Error Information Handle is a **handle**, not an error.

I haven't reviewed the specs on your ASUS V-PRO Z77 but as a rule of thumb, I would never mix ECC and non-ECC modules in the same build. AFAIK, it's not usually a supported configuration. Furthermore, don't blindly trust the output of `dmidecode` as it does not scan your hardware, it only reports what the BIOS told it to.

Sources:

http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/

[https://www.amazon.com/Corsair-CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9-240-pin-1600mhz-non-ECC/dp/B00FZ5V18K](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FZ5V18K)

https://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR1333D3E9S_4GHC.pdf

Comment: I want to clarify: I have KVR13N9S8/4 without ECC, not KVR1333D3E9S/4GHC.